# Efficiency of Matrix Multiplication; least number of operations

Tags: matrices, matrix-equations

In which order should the following product of four matrices ABCD be evaluated so as to perform the least number of operations?

A is a 1 by 5 matrix,
B is a 5 by 100 matrix,
C is a 100 by 10 matrix,
D is a 10 by 5 matrix.

---

I have what seems to be conflicting information on how to solve this problem. Research on the internet leads me to believe that I compute the efficiency one way, however my professor seems to have given me an entirely different and conflicting formula. I'm not sure if two different approaches are used two solve two slightly different wordings of similar questions, like solving for total number of operations versus solving for total number of multiplications.

From what I have read on the internet, I believe that the answer to this problem would be (((AB)C)D) is the order with the least amount of operations, with a total number of operations calculated at 1550.

To elaborate on my conflicting sources of information, here is an example. Given the above values, if we were to multiply (AB)C:

The internet has shown me the # of operations is (1)(5)(10) + (1)(100)(10).

Contrast this with my professor's in class example of:
(1)(100)(2(5) - 1) + (1)(10)(2(100) - 1).

These are clearly very different approaches to solving this problem, and I am wondering where my misunderstanding is. Are these two approaches solving a different problem entirely (such as number of multiplications vs number of operations)? Or is one approach completely wrong? Thanks in advance for any input.

Comment: @Element118 I am not sure? I've pretty much been given as much information as you see here. Can you enlighten me as to the nature of your question?

Comment: @Element118 I appreciate the link but I had visited that page already prior to posting this. That does not give me a better understanding of what I misunderstand.

Comment: @Element118 Ok so what would be your answer to the initially proposed question then? I'm aware there are multiple approaches. The question is which order has the least amount of operations?

Comment: How did you determine the order to be smallest by ((AB)C)D? It wasn't just guess and check was it?

Comment: @VladK watch this quick 10 minute video. https://m.youtube.com/watch?v=vgLJZMUfnsU   ....however you should notice that the nature of this question is the fact that the method used in that video gives number of multiplications rather than operations. To find total operations you need to consider how many multiplications AND additions there are. The answer posted below shows the difference between those two things.

Comment: Thanks. I will soon. Btw, (a(bc))d is less operations than ((ab)c)d

Comment: @VladK would you mind explaining to me how you came to that answer? I spent quite a bit of time making sure my math was right.  And my math shows that what I proposed is far more efficient than what you just proposed.

Comment: No problem. My work is in the image found in the following link. #2 and #3 specifically for the two we are talking about. http://toughstem.com/problem-answer-solution/2962/following-product-four-matrices-evaluated-perform-least-number-operations-abcd-matrix-matrix?2963. You evaluated with mq*(2n-1) as the formula for operations, correct?

Comment: @VladK I am quite positive that the picture posted in your link is not correct. You partially understand the process but don't follow through with all the operations correctly. The video I posted earlier will solve your misunderstanding if you can follow what he is saying. I assume you are in csci 340 with dundar since you also commented on a very specific question last week. I did verify the process I used with him personally. I recommend you double check your work.

Comment: @VladK it seems that your misunderstanding lies with the fact that when you multiply 2 matrices together, you have an entirely new matrix with new dimensions. Figure out the new dimensions (which is row of a by column of b) and then repeat the multiplication process with the next matrix that you multiply by. Add the number of operations rather than multiply them (as you do in your example). Do this again for the third matrix multiplication and add the total of that multiplication to the number of operations.

Comment: Thank you, friend. I watched the video and saw the flawed logic in my previous work.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think I see the problem now. The number of operations also include the addition of the numbers after you multiply them out. Although $p\times q$ multiplied by $q \times r$ is $pqr$ *multiplications*, there are also $(q-1)$ *additions* for each of the $p\times r$ entries, making a total of $pr\times(2q-1)$ *operations*.

The best algorithm to find the number of operations may not be similar to the best algorithm to find the number of multiplications, but an easy to understand algorithm to do both so is of $O(n^3)$ time complexity, with $n$ being the number of matrices. Basically, it relies on finding the number of operations required to multiply a subarray of matrices in order to find the number of operations required to multiply larger subarrays of matrices.

Comment: Bravo. That's what I was digging for. I assumed that was the difference but was unable to prove it.